# Edit “continue shopping” button styling and position in woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, button, woocommerce

I'm just trying to move and change styling to a button on a single product woocommerce page. The button is "continue shopping (SEGUIR COMPRANDO in spanish)".

What I want is to have both buttons together and horizontal, and, if it's possible, with the same style (transparent with black border). To explain myself better, I attach an image. The product link is: https://maikaihealthyfood.es/producto/combo-guacamole-chips-de-platano/

this is how it looks actually (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW6Nf.png)

this is how it should looks (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXxhZ.png)

Thank in advance!

Comment: Try `display:inline-block` on the div surrounding it

Answer (score 0):

This will help you fix your problem..[image]

```js
 // add this in footer in script tags
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-atc").addClass("seguir-btn");
  });
```

```css
/* add this to your css */
a.btn-atc.seguir-btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! What's the file where I have to add the js code? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have files knowledge of WordPress??